# Taking the Conditional Expectation of two random variables

Tags: variance, mean, random-variable, conditional-expectation

I have to find the mean and variance of $$ \beta_h $$ conditional on X

We are told:

$$ \beta_h = X^{t}Y / X^{2} $$
$$ Y | X ~is ~distributed~ N( \beta X, \sigma^{2} ) $$ 
$$ E[X] = 0 ~and ~Var[X] = w^{2} $$

From this information we know that

$$ E[\beta_h] = cov(X,Y) / w^{2} $$

Therefore, are we basically trying to find the expected value of the covariance between X and Y given X? In which case this would be zero, as the covariance of a constant and a RV is zero? I am pretty stuck, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you condition on $X$, you are treating $X$ as if it were no longer random--it's a constant (conditional on itself).  Thus $\beta_h$ is merely a linear transformation of $Y$, whence its moments are easily derived from those of $Y$.

Comment: So would it be BX? @whuber or would it be the argument i laid out earlier, where covariance is zero?

Comment: Neither.  Would it be a little clearer to write the (conditional constant) vector $X/X^2$ as, say, $u$?  The question is asking you to compute the mean and variance of $u^\prime Y$ given the mean of the vector $Y$ is the vector $\beta X$ and its covariance matrix is $\sigma^2$ times the diagonal.